# Submit value of a table with ajax to python method using flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I've recently learned of flask and I am trying to write a small web tool to help me organize data. On one page I print out a table of list numbers and their descriptions. I have jQuery script that will allow me to double click on what I want to select but I am having an issue requesting the data I POST with an ajax call. Everything works with regards to this code with the sole exception of redirecting to a new url with the data. The jQuery code to select specific rows, and double clicking all work but my grasp on the sending the data back with the POST and ajax request is lacking. My ultimate goal is to allow the user to double click on specific row in the table and it will send the number in the first column to the next page. When I run this nothing happens.

The flask python code for the particular section is here,

```
@app.route('/shelved/<user>', methods=['POST'])
def shelved(user):
    userinfo = dict(name='name', user='name', email='name@email.com')
    shelvedFiles = getInfo(user)
    if request.method =='POST':
        cl = request.form['cl']
        return redirect(url_for('change', cl=cl))
    return render_template('select_cl.html', userinfo=userinfo, shelvedFiles = shelvedFiles)
```

The html for the table is here:

```
<h2>Available Changelists for {{ userinfo.name }}</h2></br>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>CL #</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
{% for entry in shelvedFiles %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ entry.clnum }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
    </tr>
{% else %}
<li><em>No shelved changelists!</em></li>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

and the corresponding css:

```
.selected         { background-color: #1B1B1B; font-color: black; }
```

The javascript I use to highlight the line in the table, the function for the double click, and the ajax POST call is here,

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
  });
  $('#table tr').on("dblclick",  function(e){
    var cl = $("#table tr.selected td:first").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for('shelved', user=userinfo.user) }}",
        data: {'cl' : cl},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
  });       
});</script>
```

My original ajax call was this,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url_for('shelved', user=userinfo.user) }}",
  data: {'cl' : cl},
  type: 'POST',
  success: function() {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```

I would see in the developers tab in Chrome that the POST was successful. So I changed it to log the response(the original jQuery code I posted) and I could see the html for the url I WANT to redirect to in the console as well as the correctly passed data. I thought that maybe it was in issue with the page I redirected to and the flask function for that but I wrote a hacked, static version and it worked fine. This only began when I included the jQuery and ajax call. Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So you're sending data to the Flask back-end with Ajax and getting a response, which is a redirect to another page. The reason that it's not working like you intended is because you're getting a response from Flask in your *Ajax* call. You're getting back the new URL, you just haven't done anything with it.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url_for('shelved', user=userinfo.user) }}",
  data: {'cl' : cl},
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            window.location.href = data; // navigate to the new URL
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```